# SQLException: [Vertica][VJDBC](100161) The connection is closed

Tags: java, grails, jdbc, vertica

I use grails, vertica, tomcat. all is working fine until about one day after the application started. i get Exceptions.

```
java.sql.SQLException: [Vertica][VJDBC](100161) The connection is closed.
```

and

```
[Vertica][JDBC](10040) Cannot use commit while Connection is in auto-commit mode.
```

Comment: Are you able to connect from different applications?

Answer (score 0):

I solve it myself. this is caused by grails' connection pooling. I had set pooled=false in external java property file. but this won't work. i have to use groovyslurper config.